# Android TextToSpeech addSpeech() is not working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an HD Desire phone with android 2.3.

The TTS is working fine and it speaks every text I give. But when I use this either of the lines below to set my own voice for some texts, it simply ignores it and synthesizes the text, just like the line is not written!

```
tts.addSpeech("salam", "/sdcard/salam.wav");
tts.addSpeech("shalam", "com.company.appname", R.raw.shalam);
...
tts.speak("salam", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);  //<--This isn't playing my voice file.
tts.speak("shalam", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);  //<--Neither is this
```

I am sure of the existence of both files.
Why is that? Is there any restriction on the sound files? For example on their Frequency, or being mono or stereo?

I already checked the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) and saw nothing related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found my problem, very silly situation which wasted several hours of mine!! I hope it will help if someone makes my mistake.

We should postpone this mapping of texts to the point TTS is successfully initialized, for example in `onInit` function:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        mapVoices();
    }
    else
        ...
}

private void mapVoices()
{
    tts.addSpeech("salam", "/sdcard/salam.wav");
    tts.addSpeech("shalam", "com.company.appname", R.raw.shalam);
    //...
}
```

Comment: I faced same problem, but in my case problem was .wav file! .mp3 worked fine.

Comment: What is mapVoices() ?

Comment: @ktos1234 it's a custom method that maps the texts to voice files. I edited my answer to be more clear.