# Android TTS(Text to Speech)'s addSpeech() and speak() can't play a sound file in the external storage from marshmallow(api 23) above, with Google TTS

Tags: android, file, text-to-speech, android-6.0-marshmallow

As you might know, with **addSpeech()** in android TTS, you can link a certain text to a sound file. Then, the tts engine plays the file instead of synthesizing the sound of the text.

With Google TTS (not Samsung TTS), from Marshmallow(api 23) above, addSpeech & speak can't play a file in the external storage. Before Marshmallow everything was OK.

Those who have used android tts and addSpeech, please take a look at the codes below and help me find the problem.

- The codes were originally from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/MediaPlayerandTexttoSpeech.htm, and I modified them to prove my point.
- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is in manifest and TargetSDK is set to 22 to avoid marshmallow runtime permission issues.
- You need to put boy.mp3 in DOWNLOADS folder in your device.
  ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61874191/boy.mp3 )
- The code works fine in below 22 devices and Samsung TTS. It doesn't work from 23 above and with Google TTS.
- If I save the file in the internal storage (with MODE_WORLD_READABLE) it works fine even with Google TTS. But MODE_WORLD_READABLE is now deprecated, so I'd prefer external storage.
- Thank you for your attention, and have a good day.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.woojung.addspeechex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextToSpeech t1;
    EditText ed1;
    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toSpeak = "boy";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                File destinationPath = new File(dir, "boy.mp3");

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[]{destinationPath.toString()}, null, null);

                t1.addSpeech(toSpeak, destinationPath.toString());
                t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (t1 != null) {
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:transitionGroup="true">

    <TextView android:text="Text to Speech" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tutorials point"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff7aff24"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Enter Text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ff7aff10"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff23d1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Synthesize the editText."
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AddSpeech and play boy.mp3"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**build.grade(module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.woojung.addspeechex"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.woojung.addspeechex">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could it be a timing issue [as in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123410/android-texttospeech-addspeech-is-not-working)? I see `addSpeech()` is triggered by a button press, but if you are quick, you might trigger it before the TTS engine has been initialized. (i.e. before `onInit()` has been called)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen 
It could be, considering MediaPlayer's prepare() takes time. 
I wrapped speak() with Timer like below, but still no luck. (In my real project, addSpeech is done in onResume way ahead of speak(). Thanks, anyway.

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    (a)override     
                    public void run() {
                        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                }, 2000);

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @brandall No. Have you?

Comment: I'm asking Google to check into this issue in the link below. Please support me if you want this issue to be resolved at the api level. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152671139