# permission denied for writing in the path returned by getFilesDir()

Tags: java, android, exception, permissions, text-to-speech

I need to create an audio file with [synthesizeToFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)).

It works on Android 6 (with the overloaded version of [synthesizeToFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%2520android.os.Bundle,%2520java.io.File,%2520java.lang.String))) but in Android 4.1 `synthesizeToFile` returns `-1`.

The [`synthesizeToFile` official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> Synthesizes the given text to a file using the specified parameters. This method is asynchronous, i.e. the method **just adds the request to the queue of TTS requests and then returns**.

Then, to know which error caused that `-1` I searched in the logcat where I founded this exception:

> E/TextToSpeechService: Can't use /data/data/com.domain.my/files/_12345_test.wav due to exception java.io.IOException: open failed: **EACCES (Permission denied)**

There is some different system configuration/setting between Android 6 and 4.1 which cause this error?

I must pass to `synthesizeToFile` a different path than the one returned by `getFilesDir()`?

I must set file permissions?

Code I used for Android 4.1:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this, "com.google.android.tts");

public void onInit(int status)
{
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        String textToGenerate = "this is a test";
        // /data/data/com.domain.my/files is returned by getFilesDir()
        String completePathFile = "/data/data/com.domain.my/files/_12345_test.wav";

        File fileToGenerate = new File(completePathFile);
        String fileName = fileToGenerate.getName();

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, fileName);

        int response = tts.synthesizeToFile
        (
                textToGenerate
                , hashMap
                , completePathFile
        );
        Log.d("testTTS", "Generation file " + fileName + " - response = " + response);
    }
}
```

I already checked with getEngines() that "com.google.android.tts" is installed.

I need to save the file in the internal storage so I must not ask for external storage permission (it is true also for Android 4.1? Or for this versione I need to do so?).

If I deliberately pass to `synthesizeToFile` a path that doesn't exists, the error in the logcat changes to `file not found exception` so that method checks correctly that the path `completePathFile` exists.

Comment: "I must pass to synthesizeToFile a different path than the one returned by getFilesDir()?" -- based on the error, at least on some Android devices, you will need to use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) instead of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Also, please do not hard-code paths.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the comment. I hard-coded the path only to test the error, I used getFilesDir() in the complete script. How can I discover if I MUST use a different path or if I can use another way to write the file in the private internal storage as per Android 6 version? I don't give up till I see that it's impossible.

Comment: It there any device, simulator, or Android API level where this exact code ("code I used for Android 4.1") DOES work?  That would help you to cut the problem in half.

Comment: @BooberBunz the same error occurs with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your issue searching for a solution to my issue.
[Use of sound files in TTS on Marshmallow (Android 6) fails with permission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127460/use-of-sound-files-in-tts-on-marshmallow-android-6-fails-with-permission-issue)

For me, it's addspeech() in TTS.

I think permission issues on TTS come from the fact that TTS in a device is a separate application and the TTS app doesn't have permissions to write or read files in the external or internal storage of your app.

It's funny that I call the instance of TTS in my app code and use all its functions but they can't access my app's storage. TTS is not my app, so there's no way I can request permissions on behalf of TTS. I think it's a kind of bug Google has to handle.

Anyway, I let the Google team know the issue in the link below. They didn't respond yet though.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152671139

You can support me in the link above, or you can post your own issue to let them know that there're multiple developers hoping TTS permission issues are taken care of.